# What is the quickest way to get from terminal 2 to terminal 4 at JFK?

Tags: airports, airport-transfer, jfk

I know this question has been answered before, but that was 5 years ago and most airports have changed a lot since then.
On 3/6/2019 I will be travelling from Boston to Punta Cana on Delta with a layover at JFK. I only have a layover of 90 minutes and need to get from Terminal 2 to Terminal 4. What is the best way to accomplish that, and do I still not need to go through TSA screening again?
I would really appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transfer from JFK Terminal 2 to Terminal 4](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/90759/transfer-from-jfk-terminal-2-to-terminal-4), which is less than two years old.

Comment: While the link to Delta's website in the previous question now redirects to an airport map, the "jitney" is still shown on that map as running airside between Terminals 2 and 4.  So I think it's safe to say that it still runs.